# On average, what times are junglers able take each camp?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if there was some kind of document where i could review the junglespeed of each champion. I don't want to know when they get to be lvl 6, but **when they take which camp**.

Beeing able to tell where a champion is in the jungle and even more importantly, when they take their buffs, would be insanely helpful to counterjungling. This information is not yet easily available somewhere right now. I think it would suffice to only get those **times for common junglers,** but it would be helpful to have like **a time range when they take a camp** so the time is not too much off, when the jungler is slow/fast.

Comment: For starters, take a look at each champions jungling guides on popular websites. Very few people stray from these guides at the lower levels, and are still often used by higher levels.

Comment: Also keep in mind: jungling on Level 30 is much different from jungling in lower levels because of runes and masteries - they make so much difference in speed&safety especially during early game (~levels 1-6)!

Comment: Keep in mind the jungle was re-factored on 11/28/11 (Volibear patch).  Answers from before this date are no longer relevant.
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/volibear-patch-notes

Comment: unfortunately the question still stands. but it has become much harder, because its more unpredictable now. i hear for starcraft there are such timings.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i'm not sure if it is possible to create such a list. I mean some champs like warwick can start at different parts on the map so the time will always be different. Not to mention that some champions can get a little help here and there.

Also if your facing a jungle champ without smite( Boooo! ) or a jungle champ with smite the timing will be off. Also i think that some junglers are less skilled then others so it takes longer.

Or some junglers just randomize things to not get counter jungled.

The best thing fro counterjungling is imho still warding the jungle up...

Comment: yeah ofc thats the best thing. but even better would be just knowing xD. Thats why the list needs to have ranges built in. And of course, say blue is warded, would be nice to know when he will do red, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tarrasch Ofcourse it would be nice when he would do red, but don't forget even if you have a time frame for say 1 minute it still doesn't mean he will do the red in that range... he could go for a gank... wouldn't it still be best to have a ward at his red aswell and you see him comming. Instead of going there and finding out the red hasn't spawned yet or was just taken because the range said he would do it then? And he did it before or after... i mean those things are all situational and would only be good for a few players.

Answer (score 1):

For each jungling champion, you have at least two or three possible (and viable) routes. Not to mention the fact that some go straight into the enemy jungle to steal their camps.

Also, when jungling, some players go a lot more then others help teammates on their lanes (getting some damage on enemy hero for your teammate to dominate the lane or trying a gank).

All these factors (route, helping in lanes, stealing camps, getting help etc.) are variables that you can not guess from the start, so you just cannot do such a list of key times for camps.

What you can do on the other side, is buying a ward straight away to put it at enemy red or blue. I do this with twitch, when you see jungler doing it, you have time to go and gank him (easier with invisible heroes).

Answer (score 0):

Every jungling champ has different suggested routes but overall you should be leveling at par or faster than the laners. So if you're up to speed level wise and scouting the map you're jungling right.